# Using a Security token instead of a password in Python using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, security, selenium-webdriver, token

To start, I have very little knowledge in python. What I am trying to do is run a test script using selenium.

I have the token and it does not expire or ever become random.

I would like a testing software called Perfecto to open a virtual machine and run this test script that I have in python:

```
`from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By



driver1 = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\Selenium browser files\chromedriver.exe")

driver3 = webdriver.Edge(executable_path="C:\Selenium browser files\msedgedriver.exe")

driver1.get("https://google.com") #open the google browser in Chrome

driver3.get("https://google.com") #open the google browser in MS Edge

#chrome
search_box = driver1.find_element_by_name("q")
search_box.send_keys("perfecto")
search_box.submit()

C_links = driver1.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME,"a")

for link in C_links:
    print(link.text)

driver1.get_screenshot_as_file("Chrome_Results.png")

C_elm = driver1.find_element_by_partial_link_text("perfecto")
C_elm.click()


#MS Edge
search_box = driver3.find_element_by_name("q")
search_box.send_keys("perfecto")
search_box.submit()

E_links = driver3.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME,"a")

for link in E_links:
    print(link.text)

driver3.get_screenshot_as_file("Edge_Results.png")

E_elm = driver3.find_element_by_partial_link_text("perfecto")
E_elm.click()`
```

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question. Do you want the Python script to be executed inside a VM? What is the particular problem or error you are facing?

Comment: best to just automate the login and let the browser handle the token... chances are it's just stored in a cookie and added to all subsequent requests automatically.  Selenium does include set/get cookie methods but seems unnecessary.  It's most likely a session token and tied to a session.